# Recording video with ASUS Xtion using python

Tags: python, video, openni, asus-xtion

I have an ASUS Xtion 3D Sensor Camera. I want to record video with this camera by using python.

I have tried opencv using this tutorial; http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_kinect.html, but it seems that there is no video recording by using OpenNI API through OpenCV. It only shows that how to grab frames, but that is not video recording.

How can I manage to make a video recording with this camera in python?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Recorder` class to capture data into `ONI` file.
http://www.openni.ru/wp-content/doxygen/html/classopenni_1_1_recorder.html

Then you can convert `ONI` into `avi` format https://github.com/KirillLykov/oni2avi

Comment: How can I find the python API?

Comment: I've find this example https://github.com/jmendeth/PyOpenNI/blob/c7fa4fa01de3bb717ece5d036daaa343fe1c2ca9/examples/record.py I hope it's helpful